# pouchdb-find operation is very slow

Tags: angular

I followed the official page of pouchdb-find to search the latest entry and it works but it is slow. The debug shows:

```
pouchdb:find creating index +8m _design/idx-a5

pouchdb:find planning query +368ms {selector: {…}, fields: Array(7), sort}
pouchdb:find query plan +4ms {queryOpts: {…}, index: {…}, inMemoryFields: Array(1)}
```

When I first run it, the query plan takes +590ms. My issue now is I need to display the result but it takes additional seconds to be returned back to me as an observable. Is it because I am creating the Index on every call (the index id is always the same tho so I am thinking it is using already existing index). How can I improve the speed it retrieves the data? I have 1000 documents with type payment and I need one.

```
  public getData(): Observable<any> {

    let vm: any = this;

    return new Observable(observer => {

      db.createIndex({
        index: {fields: ['paidOn']}
      }).then(function () {
        return vm.local.find({
          selector: {type: 'payment', paidOn: {$gt: null} },
          fields: ['paidOn'],
          sort: [{'paidOn' : "desc"}],
          limit : 1
        }).then(function (result) {

         observer.next(result)
         observer.complete()
        }).catch(function (err) {
          // ouch, an error
          observer.error(err);
          observer.complete();
        });;
      });



    });
  }
```

then I get it :

```
  getData().subscribe(data=>{

    if (data['docs'] != undefined && data['docs'].length>0){

      console.log(data['docs'][0]);

    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you shouldn't recreate the index on every call if you aren't changing it. Try this.

```
let vm: any = this;
    vm.index = await db.createIndex({
        index: {fields: ['paidOn']}
      })
```

Move this code up here into a constructor of your object or to on onInit function.

```
public async getData(): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const result = await vm.local.find({
          selector: {type: 'payment', paidOn: {$gt: null} },
          fields: ['paidOn'],
          sort: [{'paidOn' : "desc"}],
          limit : 1
        });
    return new Observable(observer => {observer.next(result); observer.complete()});
  }
```

Although now that I'm looking at your code. You are returning an observable to get a data then immediately completing that same observable. You should keep the same observable and just use the .next() method when you want update the data or refactor this to just return a promised result and not even worry about using an observable. I'm not super clear on your use case, so I can't be certain about what is best for your situation.

Edit: Async functions return promises so I fixed return type

Comment: thanks but it made no difference speed wise at all.

Comment: as for use case, I just want to get the latest date from the document in anyway but efficiently/quickly.